# How to get type of enum values in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```
enum Enum {
  one = 1,
  two = 2,
  four = 4,
}
```

I know use `keyof typeof Enum` can get type of keys like `'one' | 'two' | 'four'`.

But how to get type of its values like `1 | 2 | 4`?